# Angular ensure list is updated without page reload

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular table that should be updated anytime someone adds an item via form. Sometimes it will display the item immediately, but other times it requires a page refresh. I have tried to use $scope.$apply as follows to refresh a REST call that feeds the list, but it is giving me the following error:

Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

My core question is can Angular listen to changes to data stored in a REST call to make a change without a page refresh, and if not, what is the best method for meeting my goal of refreshing page data after form entry?

Here is my controller for displaying data:

```
appControllers.controller('appHomeItemsCtrl', ['$scope', 'appItems', function ($scope, appItems) {

$scope.items = [];

appItems.query({}, function (data) {
    $scope.items = data.value;
// Use scope apply to watch for changes instead of requiring a page reload for results
    scope.$apply();
});
}]);
```

Here is my HTML that displays the data:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>
                   Summary
                </th>
                <th>
                    Task Type
                </th>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">

                <td>
                    {{item.Title}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{item.Body}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{item.Task_x0020_Type}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Here is my controller for adding an item:

```
appControllers.controller('appItemPostCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'appItems', 'appTypes', function ($scope, $location, appItems, appTypes) {

var itemEntry = new appItems;

 $scope.types = [];

// Get list of types for use in dropdown
 appTypes.query(function (typedata) {
     var itemTypes = typedata.value; 
    // Foreach type, push values into types array
    angular.forEach(itemTypes, function (typevalue, typekey) {

        $scope.types.push({
            label: typevalue.Title,
            value: typevalue.Title,
        });
    })
});

// Create item
 $scope.createItem = function () {
    console.log("Clicked");
    itemEntry.Task_x0020_Type = $scope.selectedtype.value;
    itemEntry.Title = $scope.itemtitle;
    itemEntry.Body = $scope.itembody;
    itemEntry.$save();
    $location.path('/');
}

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $location.path('/');
}
}]);
```

**UPDATE:** Using this, it will execute some, but not all of the time. The same is true of the answer provided regarding creating a function or push. Why does it work only "most" of the time?

```
appControllers.controller('appHomeItemsCtrl', ['$scope', 'appItems', function ($scope, appItems) {

$scope.items = [];

// Use $scope.$evalAsync to watch for changes instead of requiring a page reload for results
$scope.$evalAsync(function () {
appItems.query({}, function (data) {
                $scope.items = data.value;

    })
});
}]);
```

Comment: At which line it is throwing the error.

Comment: I can see it in the console once I load my application

Comment: You actually don't need a manual apply. What is the behaviour without apply?

Comment: See my answer below. "The exception is because you put scope, not $scope"

Comment: It requires a page refresh or routing to another page before seeing the results. The ideal situation is that a form and the results are on the same page and as I enter data, it is displayed without refresh

Comment: You must provide more code. Where is the form you are talking about? Where is the error you are talking about? There is no need to call `$scope.$apply()` here, so your error must be somewhere around, but if you don't put more code, there is no way to spot it.

Comment: appItems.query does belongs to $resource object then you don't need to use `$scope.$apply()`, use `$scope.evalAsync(function(){ //code here })` `$timeout(function(){ //code here})` for safely applying digest cycle

Comment: That works some of the time, but not all of the time. I have updated to include my form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered why it was not reloading the data all the time, it was because sometimes the $location.path would execute before the $save was complete. Wrapping $location.path or $route.reload within a $save function allows me to control execution where the $save executes before the "reload" of data occurs. I have awarded the bounty to @pasine, since his post/assistance lead me to this conclusion.

Examples:

```
$scope.addType = function () {
    console.log("Clicked");
    typeEntry.Title = $scope.itemtype;
    typeEntry.$save(function () { // Ensure execuation of the save befor reloading the view
        $route.reload();
    });
}

 $scope.createItem = function () {
    console.log("Clicked");
    itemEntry.Task_x0020_Type = $scope.selectedtype.value;
    itemEntry.Title = $scope.itemtitle;
    itemEntry.Body = $scope.itembody;
    itemEntry.$save(function () {
        $location.path('/');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are not seeing anything updating is that `$scope.items` doesn't change when you save a new item.
You can fix this issue in two ways:

**push the new item into your items after saving**

```
  $scope.createItem = function () {
    console.log("Clicked");
    itemEntry.Task_x0020_Type = $scope.selectedtype.value;
    itemEntry.Title = $scope.itemtitle;
    itemEntry.Body = $scope.itembody;
    itemEntry.$save(function(){
        $scope.items.push(itemEntry);
      });

  }
```

OR

**make a new request to retrieve all the items on the server after saving**

```
function requestItem(){
   appItems.query({}, function (data) {
              $scope.items = data.value;

    })
  });
}

// Create item
$scope.createItem = function () {
    console.log("Clicked");
    itemEntry.Task_x0020_Type = $scope.selectedtype.value;
    itemEntry.Title = $scope.itemtitle;
    itemEntry.Body = $scope.itembody;
    itemEntry.$save(function(){
      requestItem();
  });

}
```

Comment: Both methods seem to work most of the time, but if I enter data fast, it doesn't work.

Comment: I forgot to wrap the push item into a callback function in the first example

Comment: Could you update your answer with the callback? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any clues why it updates only most of the time, but not all of the time?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full code. Try to put a log after setting $scope.items and see if it is filled up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because you put `scope`, not `$scope`

But, you shouldn't really need to use apply here - unless the callback is from a non angular event. But if that is the problem, I believe you should modify $scope within the apply call:

```
appControllers.controller('appHomeItemsCtrl', ['$scope', 'appItems', function ($scope, appItems) {

$scope.items = [];

appItems.query({}, function (data) {

// Use scope apply to watch for changes instead of requiring a page reload for results
    $scope.$apply(function() {  $scope.items = data.value; });
});
]);
```

Comment: This gives me an error of: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: Then you do not need a $scope.$apply